# What does “party hands” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of *party hands* in this column by Grace Dent entitled "[If you were on your first foreign trip for 24 years, would you want Bono to be a part of the package?](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/grace-dent-if-you-were-on-your-first-foreign-trip-for-24-years-would-you-want-bono-to-be-a-part-of-7800889.html)" that appeared in *The Independent* in 2012.

> As of yet, Aung San Suu Kyi isn't meeting Hovis, sorry Jay-Z, Sean "Jolly cross about the Falklands" Penn, Bill "Don't call me **party hands**" Clinton, Bill "Butter him up for cash" Gates or any of the international "unelected force-for-good brigade". Not even Angelina Jolie has got her crazy ass an invite to stand before the political icon, one leg out like a purposeful pirate, completely festooned in kids, exuding that beatific one-love, one-world glow that comes from private jets and multiple houses.

Comment: Do you have a link to your excerpt? The context is not really clear.

Comment: http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/grace-dent-if-you-were-on-your-first-foreign-trip-for-24-years-would-you-want-bono-to-be-a-part-of-7800889.html

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea, as it seems a kind of "inside joke" to those familiar with this author's previous articles.  It might be a reference to Bill's wild lifestyle, as he is a well-known philanderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is referring to people cynically.  For example, about Bill Gates, the author is implying you can butter him up to get cash from him.

Bill Clinton is famous for philandering, and "party" sometimes is a reference to sexual activity (e.g., "party in my pants"), so "party hands" is a reference to the fact that Clinton has touched many women in a sexual way.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the "party hands" in the context of giving the nickname "Don't call me party hands" to Bill Clinton is that saying that he probably meant thousands of  hands raised (as if at a party) to greet or support him during his meetings with people:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

So, saying "Don't call me party hands" he was only trying to show modesty, in which the author of the article didn't seem to believe and called him Bill "Don't call me party hands" Clinton.

Comment: LOL.  Nice imagination, but the reference is obviously cynical.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is my take on the definition.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Party%20Hands) states that 'Party Hands' means

> When you play so much Mario Party with your bros that you get blisters on the palms of your hands.
>
> Chris: Dude what's wrong with your hands?
>
> Alex: Bro I've just been playing Mario Party 1 for the last week straight. Shit gives you party hands, bro

There have been some reports of Bill Clinton [having problems with trembling hands](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3711320/Is-Bill-ok-Viewers-Twitter-raise-concern-Clinton-s-shaking-hands-DNC-speech-little-tremor-condition-appears-worsened.html) .  Now I will leave it to your imagination as to how he would have blisters now he has trembling hands :-p